# What is the expectation of the time that the simple random walk returns to the original point?

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes

Consider a simple random walk $\{X_t\}$ on 2 dimensions, what is the expectation of the time that the walker returns to the original point? Also, can we get the expectation of the first time that the walker returns to the origin point?

I am not sure if we can get this expectation. If we define the $N$ be the times that walker returns to the original point. We know
$$\mathbb{E}(N)=\infty.$$

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "simple random walk," please?

Comment: This is vague. *If* it means a random walk on the 2-dimensional lattice of integer points, with equal probability to go east/north/west/south, we know that your $N$ (if it means the number of returns to the origin) does not only have infinite expectation, it's infinite with probability $1$. The time until the first return to the origin has infinite expectation as well, but is finite a.s. (obviously, you wouldn't return to the origin infinitely often a.s., otherwise) Beware: none of this is true for a random walk on a 3-dimensional lattice.

Comment: @ProfessorVector For the first return to the origin, why is finite a.s.? Does the infinite expectation contradict with finite a.s.?